# Recursively match and replace strings to vector element using agrep()

Tags: r, replace, string-comparison

I have 2 vectors, which are generated from varied application of `regex` to a certain pattern:

```
> v1 <- c('abc', 'efg', 'hijk', 'mno')
> v2 <- c('abcde', 'ijklm')
```

I would like to match the strings in v2 to v1 using `agrep()`,

```
> agrep(v2[1], v1, max.distance = 2)
[1] 1

> agrep(v2[2], v1, max.distance = 2)
[1] 3
```

so that the element in v1 that is closest to v2 can be replaced by v2, to give the following vector:

```
> rslt <- c('abcde', 'efg', 'ijklm', 'mno')
[1] "abcde" "efg"   "ijklm" "mno"
```

I might need a function to vary the `max.distance` number so that the closest match can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
sapply(v1, function(x) {ifelse(length(agrep(x, v2)) > 0, agrep(x, v2, value = TRUE), x)})
```

Which returns:

```
    abc     efg    hijk     mno 
"abcde"   "efg" "ijklm"   "mno"
```

Note that if the input contains for example both 'abc' and 'abcd', both will be replaced with 'abcde'. I assume this is the desired behavior? Hope this helps!

Comment: you can also do `agrep(x,v2, value = TRUE)` instead of `v2[...]`

Comment: That looks like a cleaner solution indeed, modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Florian. I know that `agrep()` returns 1 when there is a match. Why is the condition coded as:  `length(agrep(x,v2))>0` rather than `agrep(x,v2)>0`?

Comment: Hi Sati, the reason for that is that it does not return 0 when a match is not found, but rather it returns an object with length 0. (No access to R at the moment, so unable to verify this)